# How to explain "contributions that the private sector can make to enhancing..."? Is the "to" a preposition here?

Tags: prepositions, infinitive-constructions

> Recognizing and encouraging the contribution  that the private sector
>   can make to enhancing  cultural diversity and facilitating,...

My question specifically is about "make to". Why is *to* followed by the *-ing* form of the verb *enhance*? Is *to* a preposition here?

Comment: You need to write the full sentence because "to" could be used as a preposition following "contribution" or adverbial "to-infinitive". I am voting to put this question on hold for lack of context.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant phrase is "make a contribution to". This is a standard phrase, and can be followed by a clause with the verb in the "-ing" form.

Answer (score 1):

There is no component *make to* in this sentence.

Turning the relevant phrase into its own sentence, we get

> The private sector can make a contribution to enhancing cultural diversity.

Here, *contribution* is a direct object of *make*, and *to enhancing cultural diversity* is a prepositional phrase that modifies *contribution*.

So in the original sentence, *"that the private sector can make ..."* is a [relative clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause#English) that modifies *contribution*; *"contribution"* is the object of the relative clause; and *"to enhancing cultural diversity"* is a prepositional phrase modifying *contribution*.

Answer (score 0):

### Needs commas

Here's the sentence broken down into its basic form.

> Recognizing and encouraging the contribution [...] to enhancing diversity and facilitating,...

Now the "make" part of the sentence is gone.  Whoever wrote that sentence should have added commas, and this confusion wouldn't have happened, I believe.  Where did you find this sentence?

> Recognizing and encouraging the contribution, that the private sector can make, to enhancing cultural diversity and facilitating,...

"make" and "to" are independent to each other this way.